# Dynamically style children based on the parent before it jquery

Tags: jquery, function, mobile, dynamic, menu

I was wondering if I can style children dynamically with Jquery. Let me explain. I am making a mobile menu and I have it set up to where each li section only needs the class of children and then any ul inside of it will become a child that when clicked slides up/down (like an accordion) hiding/showing the options. I can do this an infinite number times. I was wondering if I can have the background color of those lists depend upon the background color of the list preceding it. For example, if li children level 1 has a background color of #cccccc then (dynamically) I want li children level 2 to realize that its parent has a background color of #cccccc and DO SOMETHING that changes the hex code to have a background color of #bbbbbb and li children level 3 to realize that its parent has a background color of #bbbbbb and DO SOMETHING that changes the hex code to have a background color of #aaaaaa...etc. My issue is the DO SOMETHING part. I've already grabbed each of these levels individually but my issue is their background color.

the css is generated from a precompiler which is why it looks weird. I usually use LESS.

```js
var hasChildren = $('.mobile-options').find('li > a');

function closeMenu(){
    $(".mobile-menu").animate({'width':'0','min-width':'0'}, 300);
    $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'auto'});
    $('.hamburger').removeClass('open');
    $('.page-overlay').fadeOut(300);
    // slides up all open menu items when menu closes
    if(hasChildren.hasClass('open')){
        hasChildren.removeClass('open');
        hasChildren.siblings('ul').delay(300).slideUp('fast');
    }
}

function dependsOnMenuButton(){
    if($('.hamburger').hasClass('open')){
        $(".mobile-menu").animate({'width':'60%','min-width':'300px'}, 300);
        $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden', 'overflow-x':'hidden'});
        $('.page-overlay').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        closeMenu();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('li').each(function(){
        if($(this).parent().parent('.children').length){
            $(this).children('a').css({'background':'yellow'});
        }
    });
    
    // allows hamburger-container, hamburger, or hamburger > span to be clicked. 
    //it does: hamburger-container or any children -> toggleClass Open
    $(".hamburger-container").click(function(){
        $(this).children('.hamburger').toggleClass('open');
        dependsOnMenuButton();
    });

    //accordion code
    //all accordion items content
    var allPanels = $('.mobile-options').find('li > ul');
    // hides all child pages lists
    allPanels.hide();
        
    //on click function for if an A tag has class children and sliding up/down their children
    hasChildren.click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('open')){
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('fast');
            // removes the class open and slides up any and all OPEN children with children elements
            $(this).parent('li').find('li.children > a').removeClass('open');
            $(this).parent('li').find('li.children > ul').slideUp('fast');
        } else if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('children')){
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown('fast');
            $(this).addClass('open');
        }
    });
});

//if user clicks outside of the menu -> close the menu
$(document).on('click', function (e){
    if($('.hamburger').hasClass('open') && $('.page-overlay').is(e.target)){
        closeMenu();
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.add-flex {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
.page-overlay {
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: none;
}
.hamburger-container {
  background: #990000;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2000;
}
.hamburger-container .hamburger {
  width: 35px;
  height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  visibility: visible;
}
.hamburger-container .hamburger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  visibility: visible;
}
.hamburger-container .hamburger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
.hamburger-container .hamburger span:nth-child(2),
.hamburger-container .hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 14px;
}
.hamburger-container .hamburger span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 28px;
}
.hamburger-container .hamburger.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 14px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
.hamburger-container .hamburger.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.hamburger-container .hamburger.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.hamburger-container .hamburger.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 14px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
.mobile-menu {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 15px 0 #131313;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content {
  width: 60vw;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-search {
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options {
  background: #fff;
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options li {
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options li a {
  padding: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options li a:visited {
  color: #000;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options li a:hover {
  background: #990000 !important;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .2s;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options li a span {
  max-width: 60%;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options .children > a {
  position: relative;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options .children > a::after {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  transition: .2s;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options .children > a.open {
  background: #990000;
  color: #fff;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options .children > a.open::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options .children > a.open:hover {
  background: #7a1705 !important;
}
.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-content .mobile-options .children ul {
  background: #eeedeb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Simple Mobile Menu</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/site.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- beginning of mobile menu button -->
        <div class="hamburger-container">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of mobile menu button -->
        <!-- beginning of mobile menu -->
        <div class="mobile-menu">
            <div class="mobile-menu-content add-flex">
                <div class="mobile-search"></div>
                <ul class="mobile-options">
                    <li class="children">
                        <a href="#">I have a child</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="children">
                                <a href="#">I'm a child with children</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="children">
                                        <a href="#">Some</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">I don't have a child</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">I don't have a child</a></li>
                    <li class="children">
                        <a href="#">I have a child</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
                            <li class="children">
                                <a href="#">I have a child</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of mobile menu -->
        <!-- page overlay -->
        <div class="page-overlay"></div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**WOW** that's a lot of code to trawl through.

Yes this can be achieved however a it would be easier to try a clever little trick.

1. Simply set a background colour (in this case `#000;`)
2. Set the list items to use an rgba colour with alpha transparancy.
   This will allow the colours to lighten or darken with each progressive layer.
   (`rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);`)

Here's a simplied example using your list items.

```css
.mobile-options,
.mobile-options li{
  list-style:none;
  padding:5px;
  background:#000;
}
.mobile-options a{
  color:#b00;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.mobile-options li {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<ul class="mobile-options">
  <li class="children">
    <a href="#">I have a child</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="children">
        <a href="#">I'm a child with children</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="children">
            <a href="#">Some</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">I don't have a child</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">I don't have a child</a></li>
  <li class="children">
    <a href="#">I have a child</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
      <li class="children">
        <a href="#">I have a child</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">I'm a child</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```